# Extract the date from filename into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to extract the date from the daily filename that i used to open using the code below. The file format that I will open everyday is the same format except the date will change to reflect the date when the file is generated. How to write in VBA to extract the date in the latest file that I opened then paste into cell, "A2" in the file?

For example, the code below will open up the latest csv file based on latest modified date with the filename, "CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_20200805_0203.csv". I just want to extract the date, "20200805" from the file name that is opened. The filename is always the same except only the date will change. How do I extract that date and paste in the cell?

```
Dim MyPathWIP As String

Dim MyFileWIP As String

Dim LatestFileWIP As String

Dim LatestDateWIP As Date

Dim LMDWIP As Date

Dim wip1 As Excel.Workbook

'Open latest file from WIP folder

MyPathWIP = "D:\Regina\Case360 reporting automation\Daily Report WIP Testing\"

If Right(MyPathWIP, 1) <> "\" Then MyPathWIP = MyPathWIP & "\"

MyFileWIP = Dir(MyPathWIP & "*.csv", vbNormal)

If Len(MyFileWIP) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

Do While Len(MyFileWIP) > 0
    LMDWIP = FileDateTime(MyPathWIP & MyFileWIP)
    If LMDWIP > LatestDateWIP Then
        LatestFileWIP = MyFileWIP
        LatestDateWIP = LMDWIP
    End If

    MyFileWIP = Dir

Loop

Set wip1 = Workbooks.Open(MyPathWIP & LatestFileWIP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next function, please:

```
Function FindDate(strFileName As String) As String
  If UBound(Split(strFileName, "_")) > 4 Then
      FindDate = Split(strFileName, "_")(4)
  End If
End Function
```

You can test it using:

```
Sub testFindDate()
  Dim fileName As String
   fileName = "CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_20200805_0203.csv"
   MsgBox FindDate(fileName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    str = "CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_20200805_0203.csv"
    
    arr = Split(str, "_")
    
    MsgBox (arr(4))
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this. Splitting the string, based on the underscore, is already shown in other answers, so let me show you how to proceed, working with the fixed string approach:

```
str_filename = "CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_20200805_0203.csv"
str_Date = Mid(str_filename,Len("CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_")+1,Len("YYYYMMDD"))
```

What does this mean?

The filename has the following format:

```
CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_YYYYMMDD_...
```

Where:

- `CCONTACT_Daily_WIP_CCONTACTCase_` is a fix string, preceeding the string you're looking for
- `YYYYMMDD` is the date format (four characters for the year, two for the month and two for the day)

The extraction (taking the substring, done by the `Mid()` function) is done by:

- Start at the length of the fix string (plus one)
- The length is defined by the length of the format